# How to link instruments in a Sibelius arrangement to instruments in a soundfont file for playback?

Tags: midi, arranging, sibelius, hand-bells

I have some arrangements of handbell music in Sibelius 7 that I'd like to play back into a track for my handbell choir to practice to.

I purchased a high-quality soundfont (sf2) file of handbells with over a dozen different articulations. The problem I'm running into is that when I export the arrangement to MIDI, I don't seem to be able to specify reliably which instrument in the soundfont file is selected when I play back the arrangement into a WAV file (using Timidity++).

It selects a reasonable sound when I change the instruments in the Sibelius arrangement to "Electric Piano." If I don't do anything, it selects the bell shake articulation for every note. If I try to add an instrument into Sibelius that matches one of the instruments in the soundfont file (which I've shown below loaded into Polyphone) it doesn't play back using that articulation.

[image]

Has anyone had success with something similar to this, or could point me in the right direction for finding what to link up where?